# pagination working but not displaying correctly

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

My pagination is working great on my website, www.scottiescotsman.com
But for some apparent reason it is not working correctly on this page ..

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="col-md-12">
<?php bd_pagination(); ?>
</div>
<?php
$args = array(
'post_type'         => 'movies',
'orderby'           => 'name',
'order'             => 'ASC',
'tax_query'         => array(
    array(
    'taxonomy'      => 'genre',
    'field'         => 'slug',
    'terms'         => 'drama'
    )
)
);
$drama = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $drama->have_posts() ) : while ( $drama->have_posts() ) : $drama->the_post();
$sto = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "storyline", true ); ?>
<div class="row" style="color: #ddd;">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h3><?php echo the_title(); ?></h3></a><p><b style="color: #fff">Storyline&nbsp;:</b>&nbsp;<?php echo $sto; ?></p>
    </div>
</div>  
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : echo '<p>NO CONTENT FOUND</p>'; ?>
<?php endif; ?> 
<div class="col-md-12">
<?php bd_pagination(); ?>
</div>
<?php get_template_part( 'second-footer' ); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

hope someone can help with this problem

Steven

Comment: HOW is it not working correctly? What's the difference between that page and others where it works.

Comment: it doesn't display correctly .. as in keeps showing page 1 ... but splits the query list correctly

Comment: Where does bd_pagination() comes from ? Hard work for this function to paginate datas that doesn't exists yet :-)

Comment: its a function I added in functions.php to control the pagination